# GWT Compiler Optimizations: When are they safe?

Tags: java, gwt, optimization

When are the following compiler optimizations safe/sensible to add:

```
-XdisableClassMetaData
-XdisableCastChecking
compiler.stackMode
compiler.enum.obfuscate.names
CssResource.obfuscationPrefix
CompilerParameters.gwt.xml.*
```

Do some only make sense in Dev (or Prod) mode? Do any present security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-XdisableClassMetaData - safe when you don't use Object.getClass() method.

-XdisableCastChecking - I would personally never use this. But if you do not use polymorphism at all you may try.

compiler.stackMode - "strip" for prod and "emulated" for dev

compiler.enum.obfuscate.names - recommended to use in prod.

CssResource.obfuscationPrefix - use when you need partially obfuscated css

For the last one you can find some documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/CompilerParameters.gwt.xml)

Only compiler.enum.obfuscate.names influences security vulnerability (so set it to true in prod). 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I use `XdisableCastChecking` in prod, because `ClassCastException` should be detected at dev time anyway (aren't they somehow a sign of _code smell_?)

Comment: I think what you are saying makes sense, but only for small projects. There is no way to try every possible execution path in medium/big system under dev even if you have pretty good test code coverage. Having class cast exception in prod is much better than weird javascript errors which would be raised if there is no class cast check, as for first ones it's much easier to figure out the cause.

Comment: My opinion is that the risk is small enough, even for big projects. Of course YMMV. (I'm almost certain Google uses `XdisableCastChecking`, why would have they added it otherwise? and they have bigger projects than I have, with a much bigger and more critic user base)

Comment: This might be true, but Google also has few level of tests for most of the projects, which is not always the case for other companies (at least for my not that big experience)